# SWIFT - Transparent Button

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I want to place button at the bottom of the screen and also want to make it little transparent.

Here I am sharing my code with image. Can please any one suggest me like how to make button transparent and how to change the position.

card.swift

```
//
//  testCard.swift
//  demoApp
//
//  Created by ZAREEN NAUSHAD on 17/01/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct testCard: View {
    var testItem : testCourse
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image(testItem.testImage)
                
                
                
            VStack{
                Text(testItem.testName)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                Text("Marks: " + testItem.testMarks)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                Text("Minute: " + testItem.testTime)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                Text("Question: " + testItem.testQuestion)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            }.offset(y : -160)
            
            Button(action: ({
                print("Button Clicked")
            }), label: {
                HStack{
                    Text("Take Test Now")
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("LCOdarkpink"))
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.right.square")
                        .accentColor(Color("LCOdarkpink"))
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .background(Color.white)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
            }).offset(y : 0) // here i am trying to change the position of button but its not moving
        }
        .frame(width: 280, height: 430)
        .background(testItem.testColor)
        .cornerRadius(18)
    }
}

struct testCard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        testCard(testItem: testList[1])
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using offsets to change the position of your elements you can use a `Spacer()` inside a `VStack()`. To change the transparency of the button you can use the `.opacity()` modifier.

You could try something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            //Image(testItem.testImage)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .fill(Color(.blue))
            
            VStack {
                Text("testItem.testName")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                Text("Marks: " + "testItem.testMarks")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                Text("Minute: " + "testItem.testTime")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                Text("Question: " + "testItem.testQuestion")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                
                Spacer() // <-- 1. Spacer instead of offset
                
                Button(action: ({
                    print("Button Clicked")
                }), label: {
                    HStack{
                        Text("Take Test Now")
                            .fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.black))
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.right.square")
                            .accentColor(Color(.black))
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                    .background(Color.white
                            .opacity(0.8)) // <-- 2. Change transperancy of button here
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                })
            }.padding()
            
        }
        .frame(width: 280, height: 430)
        .background(testItem.testColor)
        .cornerRadius(18)
    }
    
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the result]